# Save output devcon.exe in .txt

Tags: cmd

I need save the output to devcon in a .txt, if I use the command lines I don't have a problem but I when use a batch file, this create the file but the file is empty.

This is the command line in my batch file:

> devcon.exe status * > file.txt

Comment: Do you want to save the outut of `devcon.exe` or `devcon.exe status *` to file.txt? If it's only devcon.exe, `devcon.exe > file.txt` should work ... or I didn't get well your question. OR: does `devcon.exe status *` (without the redirection) has an output (I mean write something on the screen) ?

Comment: Hi, I want to save devcon.exe status * to file.txt, Yes it has a output

Comment: 1./ Is it a normal output or an error output? 2./ Do you have the rights to write in file.txt?

Answer (score 1):

A test here (windows 8.1) shows me that `devcon` outputs to a different console screen if you don't run as administrator.

So right click the batch file and run it as administrator.

Comment: Hi, I run it as administrator (windows 7) but the batch file create the file empty

Comment: Did you right click it and run it with elevated permissions?  Using an administrator account is not sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I have got it if I open cmd with run it as administrator but if I make it with batch file, it not working